# Find where {fn(x)} n=1 to infinity converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

$f_n(x) =  \frac{6}{(1+x^{2n})}$  and x ∈ R

Find all real numbers x where fn(x) converges pointwise and describe the limit function.

I found the limit function to be $f(x)= 0$ if |x|>1, 6 if 0 < x < 1, and 3 if |x| = 1

So fn(x) converges pointwise for all  x ∈ R.

Now I have to find the intervals for which fn(x) converges uniformly to f(x). I am considering the intervals [0,1) and (1, infinity). But do not know where to go from here.

Comment: If $|x|>1$, what happens when you compute higher and higher powers? Likewise what happens when $|x|<1$? What happens when $x=\pm 1$?

Comment: If x>1 and as x gets bigger, f(x) gets closer to 0. If x<1 and x gets smaller, then f(x) gets closer to 6. If x=1, the f(x)=3 and if x=-1 then f(x) DNE. So fn(x) converges pointwise for real numbers > -1. And the limit function is f(x) ={ 3 if x=1, DNE if x=-1, 6 if x<1, 0 if x>1

Comment: @Mark: careful... if $x=-1$, $x^{2n}=1$ for all integers $n$.